# Issue with DECIMAL in MySql

Tags: mysql, outofrangeexception

```
CREATE TABLE NMSA (
    customer_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    age INT,
    level VARCHAR(20),
    gender VARCHAR(20),
    time_slot NUMERIC(4,2),
    joining_frequency INT,
    season_preferences VARCHAR(20),
    discount INT,
    allocated_coach VARCHAR(20),
    branch VARCHAR(20),
    client_feedback VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO NMSA VALUES(123, 'Abhinav', 34, 'Competitive', 'Male', 9.0, 12, 'All', 0, 'Nisha', 'Turfpark', 'Excellent');
```

**Error is:** Out of range value for column 'time_slot' at row 1

Comment: i can't reprocuce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3dafc08118051896a18758909611c51d

Comment: I tried your same code but I didn't get any error.